# How do I use LINQPad scripts in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, linqpad

**Question.**
How do I use LINQPad scripts in Visual Studio?

**Description.**
I created the `Class Service.linq` class in `LINQPad`.
How can I use the `Class Service.linq` class in `Visual Studio`?

In other words, can I implement the following scenarios?
Scenarios:

- import `ClassService.linq` to the project in `Visual Studio`;
- synchronize `ClassService.linq` with the project in `Visual Studio`;

(*synchronization logic:*

- *changed `ClassService.linq` ->> changed project in `Visual Studio`;*
- *changed `ClassService. linq` < < - changed the project in `Visual Studio`;*)

Can I implement all or part of these actions?

Or is `LINQPad` used for preliminary development of solutions, and then the code is manually transferred to the `*.cs` files?

**Is used**

- LINQPad - 6.9.15x64;
- Visual Studio - 2019. Community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't easily share source code in this manner because the .linq format has an XML header with the query properties (rather like the info in a Visual Studio project file).

However, you can share DLLs by referencing DLLs that you create in VS from LINQPad. LINQPad will automatically locate the .deps.json file if present, and integrate your project's NuGet references into the query. You can access the assembly's internal types from LINQPad if you add the following to a source code file in your project:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("LINQPadQuery")]
```

To share a DLL, do the following:

Press <kbd>F4</kbd> from LINQPad, click 'Add/Browse', choose a DLL that you created in VS (from the bin\debug folder). That folder will also contain a .deps.json file created by VS which lists all your project's NuGet dependencies. LINQPad will automatically read this file and add those NuGet packages to your query. There's an InternalsVisibleTo example here: 
[danclarke.com/linqpad-tips-and-tricks-part2](https://www.danclarke.com/linqpad-tips-and-tricks-part2)

Comment: **1.** `referring to DLLs created in VS from LINQPad` - I don't understand what this means. Could you describe in more detail how this happens?

**2.** `LINQPad will automatically find the .deps.json file,` - How does this happen? Whose `.deps.json`  File is this and where is it located? In a VS or LINQPad project?

**3.** - `you can access internal build types from LINQPad if you add the following to your project's source code file: [assembly: *]` - could you give a more detailed example.

**4.** - Where can I get detailed documentation on working with LINQPad ?

Comment: Press F4 from LINQPad, click 'Add/Browse', choose a DLL that you created in VS (from the bin\debug folder). That folder will also contain a .deps.json file created by VS which lists all your project's NuGet dependencies. LINQPad will automatically read this file and add those NuGet packages to your query. There's an InternalsVisibleTo example here: https://www.danclarke.com/linqpad-tips-and-tricks-part2

Comment: I don't understand ...
what does Nugget have to Do with it? 
If possible, I will be grateful if you explain the steps that need to be done.
If I understand you, I see it this way. 
Example:
**1.** `VS` Create a project in (example: WinForms);
**2.** Create the `Class Service.cs` class; 
**3.** `VS`.`class Service.cs` Create methods `Method1()`, `Method2()`;
**4.** `VS`. Press F6.;
**Question:** How can I use (make changes, debug) the `Class Service.cs` class in the LINQPad program?

Comment: I think I figured it out...
I made changes to your answer.
If I understand correctly, you can use the same project in `LINQPad` and `VS`only using the scheme: create a DLL in VS and add the created DLL to the 'LINQPad' project. Result: in the VS project, I can change the DLL methods, and in the `LINQPad` project I can only use the DLL, but I can't change the methods of the DLL.

Comment: **Questions.**  
**1.** do I understand you correctly?
If I understand something wrong, could you please correct me?
**2.** Are there ways to use the same project in `LINQPad` and `VS`?
In other words: there Is a project `Project-1`. I made changes to the project `Project-1` in the program `LINQPad`. The resulting changes can be viewed in `VS`. And I made changes to the project `Project-1` in the program `VS`. As a result of the change, you can go to `LINQPad`.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite way is possible: LinqPad 6 now allows to **share `*.cs` files.** Instead of trying to open a .linq file in Visual Studio, you can write your class and store it as .cs file.

This has the following benefits:

- Visual Studio natively "understands" .cs files
- LinqPad can load .cs files, so you can share the same file with Visual Studio

To do this, create a new "C# Program" in LinqPad.

Suppose you have a file `KeyValueClass.cs`:

```
using System;

namespace myRedisDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class for key / value pair
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>{"Key":"name", "Value":"Matt"}</example>
    public class KeyCalueClass
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The key
        /// </summary>
        public string Key { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The value
        /// </summary>
        public string Value { get; set; }
    } // class

} // namespace
```

You want to use it in `ReferenceCsFiles.linq` in the

 directory `C:\Users\Matt\source\repos\A. Demos\myRedisDemo\`as follows:

```
#load "C:\Users\Matt\source\repos\A. Demos\myRedisDemo\KeyCalueClass.cs"

void Main()
{
    var obj = new myRedisDemo.KeyCalueClass();
    obj.Dump();
}
```

This will compile the `KeyValueClass.cs` file from your Visual Studio project and run it in LinqPad.

---

You can even import all .cs files with wildcards like

```
#load "C:\Users\Matt\source\repos\A. Demos\myRedisDemo\*.cs"
```

and with all subdirectories like:

```
#load "C:\Users\Matt\source\repos\A. Demos\myRedisDemo\*.cs /s"
```

Finally, if you omit the path like

```
#load "KeyCalueClass.cs"
```

then it will refer to the same path where the .linq file is. So you could save the supporting *.linq file in the same directory with your classes and just reference the *.cs file(s) without a path.

Comment: Now that's an excellent and mighty useful tip thanks @Matt

Comment: @Rax - Good to hear! :-)